Maui: TabbedPage - menu colors [Windows]
I have a TabbedPage in my Maui app - there are too many tabs to display, so an ellipse is shown and when you click it, you're supposed to see the names of the other tabs. For me, the font color is the same as the background color, so I can't read the name!
Does anyone know what setting name is used for that menu? (background, text colour and also when hovering)?


You can reset the text color by using the property BarTextColor of TabbedPage.
Please refer to the following code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiTabApp.HomePage"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MauiTabApp.pages"
            
              BarTextColor="Red"
             Title="HomePage">

       <!--   For the sake of brevity, the other codes are omitted.  --> 

</TabbedPage>


          


Thank you for that, yes, it does appear to use the BarTextColor for the menu text, but still not worked out what that background colour of the menu is, it's not using BarBackgroundColor.

For this problem, you can create a new issue here. Thanks for your support and feedback for Maui.

I've logged this issue on GitHub - it's possible it's not really an issue, and I've missed something obvious, but will see what feedback comes back :-) https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/26754

Thanks for your support and feedback for Maui. :)
